# Numerical Issue with KS-Test (difference in D-Value when switching alternative)

Tags: r

I am new to R, but quite experienced in statistics. I have found that `R-ks.test()` behaves different wrt. D-Value (the TestStatistics) when changing the hypothesis formulation:

I have one dataset, on which I ran 3 versions of the KSTest: alternative = 'greater', 'less', 'two.sided'. Yes, these 3 runs will give me 3 different p-values, BUT I ASSUME, these 3 runs shall give me THE SAME KS-Value (D), or am I wrong?

See code below, marked by (<<=== PROBLEM HERE ??? )

Define Data:

```
data <- c(-0.82, -0.46, 0.86, 0.07, 0.46, -0.39, 0.92)
```

Run 1

```
ks.test(data, "pnorm", 0, 1, alternative = 'greater')

One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  data
D^+ = 0.17879(<<=== PROBLEM HERE ??? ), p-value = 0.574
alternative hypothesis: the CDF of x lies above the null hypothesis
```

Run 2

```
ks.test(data, "pnorm", 0, 1, alternative = 'less')

One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  data
D^- = 0.20611, p-value = 0.4895
alternative hypothesis: the CDF of x lies below the null hypothesis
```

Run 3

```
ks.test(data, "pnorm", 0, 1, alternative = 'two.sided')

One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  data
D = 0.20611, p-value = 0.874
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

---

I would expect that the D-Value with alternative = 'greater' also would be 0.20611, as with the other 2 cases, or am I wrong?

Here I did not find a clue: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dgof/versions/1.2/topics/ks.test

Many thanks and may the FSM be with u all.

Comment: One can view the source code by typing just "ks.test".

Comment: MATLAB does the same:

    [H,P,KSSTAT,CV] = kstest(x, 'Tail', 'larger')

So it seems to be OK.